# Keep getting called on my personal phone

Tags: professionalism, communication, personal-property

Being the IT/DBA/Networks/Programmer of our company, I'm used to have the office phone ringing every 5 min if not more. I can manage it, although a bit frustrating when I'm trying to program or go through my predecessor's code since I need time to focus and go line by line debugging it. But other than that I'm pretty used to it.

A couple of weeks ago, I started getting calls to my personal phone. The first time I was at lunch, just to ask me if they could use their machine (It was updating) clearly something that could wait the 30 min I had left for lunch. Then, I started receiving more calls to my personal phone, before clocking in, during lunch and even during my days off to visit home(that one really annoyed me, I was already 600 miles away visiting my family and a user was calling me so I could check up his computer) this was the drop that made me lose my patience.

The one transferring all the calls is the receptionist, I once had to call in due to a sickness and well she kept my phone. I've asked her several times since the first incident that I don't want her to transfer calls to my personal phone unless it's an emergency. Her response was a bit neutral but agreeing to my request, and I thought that was the end of it, yet she keeps transferring the calls nonetheless.

Due to this, I wanted to ask if I have the right to ask for a company phone specific for the purpose to receive calls transferred from the receptionist.

***UPDATE***: I've accepted [enderland's](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/69925/46494) answer mostly cause of the suggestion of request by e-mail system with a ticketing system in the long run, I sent an email to the users stating that I would like to implement a system via e-mail for their request, telling them that it would help me help them. Since it would be more organized and I would be able to keep track of every situation since we would have paper trail, I haven't had a response from everyone but the ones that have, they replied in a positive way and are actually using their e-mail to submit their requests, sure my inbox will suffer (joking) but so far its proven to keep the situation under control, I am able to write automatic responses when I'm outside the office and some even mark the message as important when the situation is really important(blue screen or what not) and I'm really happy about it.

I also want to mention [Nelson's](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/69955/46494) suggestion about letting know the receptionist how to handle the remaining calls that come through when I'm not at the office. It's proven to be helpful to provide the receptionist with this custom message.

A third partial solution would be [Burhan's](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/70037/46494) third suggestion: To rotate the on-call duty. We're only 2 in the office, but I feel it will help the office in the long run, and my colleague seems to agree with the idea.

As a summary, the majority(if not all of them) of the answers suggest to just restrict any calls to my personal phone, which I have taken into action I called my supervisor explaining the situation to him and he asked the receptionist to only pass his calls to my cellphone. So far everything seems to be going alright.

Comment: Insisting on doing it or agreeing not to then doing it anyway?  If she is actually insisting what is her reasoning for not respecting your request?

Comment: Your mistake is in letting the receptionist decide what an "emergency" is.

Comment: How are your calls getting to the receptionist in the first place? Are people calling her directly and asking to be transferred to your cell because they know you're not at your desk?

Comment: No, they ask to be transferred to me, and although there's another guy when I'm not at the office she still forwards them to my phone, cause they asked for me(which is not specifically cause its me, its cause the phone is in my desk, they rather just ask by name than asking to be transferred to the department). Instead of just telling them I'm not available and that she'll transfer the call to the office's phone. @AlexHowansky

Comment: @Myles edited to a more clear statement

Comment: Someone got my personal phone number and is sharing it without my consent? I would be angry. Rather than requesting the receptionist, I would demand the receptionist to forget my phone number And I would not be kind about it. I don't understand why you should be polite and respectful when someone else clearly wasn't. Or if you prefer the politically correct solution I would go to HR.

Comment: @MrMe Sometimes "polite" and "respectful" is the difference between someone getting their way and someone making enemies. Be firm about your position, but still kind. You tend to get further in life that way.

Comment: get a new phone number, don't tell it to anyone at work. problem solved!

Comment: Do the switboard forwarded calls come in on the company's phone number? You can set up a deny with custom message.

Comment: Do Not talk to the receptionist anymore.

Go straight to your manager and let him/her deal with it.

Comment: @SargeBorsch That is not a good solution, it is a big mess to get a new phone number just because someone at work does not respect your privacy

Comment: @Thebluefish Sometimes being nice and kind are the way to go - I am that way 99% of the times. But sometimes you do need to get angry. Why having to hide your feelings when someone violates your rights as this receptionist did to the OP.

Comment: My manager once gave my personal phone number to a client once. I was *NOT* amused.

Comment: Standard operating procedure everywhere I have worked for forty years is that private phone numbers are not given out: the company takes the *caller's* number and contacts you with the information: then you decide what to do about it, if anything. Anything else is a major violation of your privacy and should not be tolerated for a moment,

Comment: Depending on how reception transfers work you could selective call forwarding to forward calls from reception back to reception.

Comment: "Sorry, wrong number."

Comment: Press the red button! The receptionist will get the message eventually

Comment: Two words: "Google Voice." It will screen your personal calls. It can redirect certain calls to your work phone.

Comment: I really like the way you wrote the suggestions that worked for you (and how) into your question.

Comment: @DisplayName Getting a new phone number for my mobile phone is _extremely_ unpractical. For example in the UK there are about five million people who need their phone number to prove that they have the right to work in the UK.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

First, get a system for requesting your help. This is the main problem. Email >> phone. Train people to do this. "Can you send an email so I can keep track of this request?" People eventually will realize this is how you expect to have requests made. Long term you probably want a ticket system, but start out just requesting email.

None of the problems you are dealing with will be resolved if you don't ultimately get a request system of some sort.

Second, look into a Google Voice phone number - use this for work. It lets you forward calls only during certain time periods (work hours). There are a few services that do this, but you can give them your "work" number that is only active during hours you are available.

Third, yes, you should investigate getting a work phone. This is a great conversation starter with the receptionist and/or manager, something like "I'm not able to use my personal phone for work, what is the process to getting a company phone so I can better handle work related calls?"

Do not make it optional. Make sure your conversation is "how can we stop this?" and not "can we stop this?" You want to make the burden on the company to fix the problem, do not just ask if they will as they probably will get "no."

Comment: I'm missing the "how". Will give it a try, thanks

Comment: "I'm not able to use my personal phone for work, what is the process to getting a company phone so I can better handle work related calls?" This would seem like an ill-advised turn of phrase given that the OP is already doing so.

Comment: @jpmc26 Not bringing it to work would be quickest, easiest way to make that a true statement.  Leave it at home, leave it in the car, turn it off, whatever.

Comment: @HopelessN00b I would consider that a counterproductive solution. The reason I got a cell phone in the first place was to be able to coordinate with my family over distance, be reachable in the event of an emergency, or be able to reach someone in an emergency. Leaving it at home, turning it off, or leaving it in the car would defeat the purpose of having one (or at least some of the purpose).

Comment: @jpmc26 if you want to be that pedantic, sure. Make it "I'm not able to __continue__ to use" -- the point is making it clear that the OP will not be using it in the future for work and talking from that position and approaching the boss/receptionist from that perspective.

Comment: To enforce this, don't answer anonymous callers for a month or so. "Hm, he doesn't respond to calling, but he did to my email, guess I'll email again."

Comment: My phone has a 'priority' mode, where I can whitelist particular callers. This is a really good way of ignoring 'work' calls (anyone else can leave you a message)

Comment: Google Voice is a great way to help manage incoming calls, if you can get a free number (local to your area).  Just make sure to get a separate Google Voice number, and forward calls to whatever other number you have.  Anyone using the Google Voice number can be managed with Google Voice's tools.

Comment: A good ticket system >>> email >> phone.

Comment: No, no no! Don't ask for a work phone - you'll only get more and more calls! Instead, just simply stop answering calls when you're off the clock (unless you have a specific agreement with your company to always be "on-call").

Comment: If you don't have a ticket system, you can get Jira, Gitlab or similar very quickly.  Either a paid subscription or setting it up in-house.

Answer (score 48):

> I wanted to ask if I have the right to ask for a company phone specific for the purpose to receive calls transferred from the receptionist.

Sure, but that's not your actual problem and it's a fair bet that you're not being paid to provide that kind of availability. Only taking calls when you're at your desk was presumably fine for your position. So why subject yourself to the added stress of getting called when you're not in the office or otherwise unable to help?

The only thing you need to be doing is **going back to the receptionist** and stating clearly and in no uncertain terms that she should stop forwarding people to your personal phone. You claim to have done so before but clearly the message wasn't coming across and you need to spell this out with something like:

> I've spoken to you about this before but it seems like I wasn't clear enough. You've saved my mobile number when I called in sick the other day but that's not a work phone and people are only able to contact me for help by phone when I'm actually at my desk. Being reachable at all hours of the day is not something that the IT department offers and if I'm not at my desk there's also nothing I can do for people who call in for help. Even if people claim that they need me urgently or that there's some emergency, do not forward them. Anyone who needs to reach me in an emergency has my number so **I don't want you to call me on my cell unless the building is literally burning down.**
>
> From this point on I need you to completely stop forwarding people to my personal phone, **can you do that**?

Under normal circumstances I'd advise some follow-ups before escalating but you've already talked to her several times so you can skip that. The follow-up would go something like:

> I thought I made it clear when we spoke [yesterday / earlier] that you shouldn't forward anyone to my personal phone any more. But you've just forwarded [X / 3 people / ...] to me today. **What's going on**? [pause for dramatic effect]

If it continues, it's time to talk with whoever is managing your receptionist because ignoring reasonable requests that you are well within your right to make is just downright bizarre behaviour.

As for what to do with the people who still reach you, [gnasher729's advice](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/69930/25739) is spot-on. All you do is tell them that you're unable to help right now. If the procedures for contacting your department are lacking or unknown with the users you can add some info on how to contact you when you're not in whether that's email or an incident tracker.

Comment: You could go further than this -- since the only reason the receptionist even has this number is because he called in sick from it and she took it upon herself to record it, he can reasonably ask her to remove it from her records. Never mind the building burning down either. If the building had been on fire before that day he wouldn't have got a call to the personal phone, and the same should be true again once it's deleted. Anything you put after the word "unless" gives her an excuse to keep the number and later "forget" the restrictions on using it.

Comment: @SteveJessop Agreed. I was tempted to recommend that approach instead but reconsidered as it's probably even more aggressive. It's certainly worth considering though and as you say it could prevent the issue from starting again down the line.

Comment: There's almost certainly no need to be so foreceful in your request to the receptionist initially. OP asked her to only forward emergencies, but she doesn't have the knowledge and experience to make that judgment. The easiest step would be to **kindly and politely** ask her to only forward calls from your manager (or management chain, or some designated list), and direct everyone else to email you. If she won't do that consistently, ask her why not, and if you're not satisfied with the answer or the follow-up, bring it up with management.

Comment: @Lilienthal: I don't think it's aggressive to say something like, "Could you just remove my personal phone number from your records? I know I said it was OK to forward calls to me in emergencies, but I'm finding that people are abusing that, and honestly, there's really no reason it should ever be needed anyway." (Optionally with an "Any *real* emergency would be escalated with management" at the end, though we don't want the receptionist getting any ideas . . .)

Comment: Also, consider the possibility that some people have probably written down the phone number given out by the receptionist. This is what I would have done personally. So don't consider this issue completely closed even if you do manage to get her to delete your number.

Comment: @Novelocrat True, but that depends on the prior conversations OP had with the receptionist. I'm assuming there's been some escalation already in the language he used which is why my suggested script was on the harsh side.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with being clear and firm. No need for smileys and unicorns.

Comment: "literally burning down" and even then, can you actually do something about it? No need to get the call transferred even then.

Comment: If OP has asked the receptionist politely to stop forwarding inappropriate calls and to never give out their personal cell number (if she already had), the solution to that isn't to be harsher. It's to ask management to convey to the receptionist that OP isn't asking for a favor, but is making a mandatory request on behalf of the business.

Comment: If the building is on fire and the receptionist is calling the IT guy's personal phone, that's still a problem.  Call the fire department in that situation, FFS.  "...under no circumstances..." is the phrase you're looking for here.

Answer (score 19):

Don't answer your phone?

Is the problem that calls are coming to your personal phone, or is the problem that you're getting calls at inappropriate times?

If it's the latter, getting a work phone is not going to fix anything. If it's not business hours, it seems to me you have every right to screen your calls, and only respond (by email) if it's a real emergency.

By continuing to answer business calls before/after hours, you are simply communicating to others that it's an acceptable practice.

Eventually people will get the hint that the best way to get in touch with you is through email, during business hours.

Comment: I mention the odd times due to the fact that I'm not present where my office phone is, its mostly cause its my personal phone. The reason for which I still answer its cause it might be my direct supervisor who isnt even in the country at the moment. And thats why I pick up cause it might be him

Comment: @JustDoIt do you have caller id?

Comment: Yes, I know when its the company's phone, the issue here is that my boss sometimes messages me through a messaging service, sometimes calls me from his cellphone and sometimes calls the company and ask to be transferred(usually when he already had to contact some other department, I guess its a way to make the most of an international call)

Comment: @JustDoIt Tell your direct supervisor that you're no longer answering calls from work on your personal phone because that privilege is being abused, and use that to segue into why you should have a company-issued cell phone assigned to you as soon as possible.

Comment: A company-issued phone wont solve the problem of people abusing your private time. If people already feel entitle to walk over you with a private phone, just picture it with a company phone.

Comment: My colleagues who have company cellphones just leave them in the office when they go home.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: In Portugal, do company-issued phones not have power buttons?

Comment: You are expected to carry it with you and be available all time. Many people here carry usually two phones. Currently I have not one and would not ask for it. I already had it in several companies and depending on the company and your contract... If you are managing an isp like I was you CANNOT turn it off. Nowadays my phone enters automatically silent mode after 22

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: I think you're confusing cause and effect. Many people have company-issued cellphones *because* they're expected to be available even when not in the office; but someone who has a company-issued cellphone for a different reason is not then expected to be available at all times.

Comment: If you turn off the work phone when it isn't appropriate to get work calls, it *does* solve the problem of getting calls at inappropriate times.

Comment: Most modern smart phones have a feature to accept only selected contacts' calls when desired.  That way you can keep it available for family / school calls, but send all other calls straight to voicemail.

Answer (score 15):

**If you value your personal time, do not ask for a company phone.**

Once you are on a company phone, it is expected that you will answer each and every call, not matter what time or day it is placed. It is extremely difficult to establish boundaries. Having a company phone gives everyone the permission that its okay to bother you whenever.

You will now be **expected** to pick up the company phone whenever it rings.  Do you really want this? Unless your job requires you to be on-call, or you are in a fire-fighting role - then this is a **very bad idea**.

Now, lets suppose you are in a fire-fighting role, if so **before you even think of asking for a company phone**:

1. Establish a procedure for reporting incidents. I would highly recommend moving this away from "email me" to setting up a ticketing system. You can find many free ones online and some that you don't even have to host your self.
2. Establish strict guidelines for escalation - **and stick to them**. For the end user, everything is an emergency but it should be clear what actually constitutes an emergency. Don't let someone else dictate the escalation procedure, it should be either you or your immediate boss (if they are tech savvy).  The escalation matrix should also indicate what is the **minimum response time** for both acknowledgment, and resolution of issues for each escalation level.
3. Do not be the lone wolf. If you are part of a support team or a developer team, rotate the responsibility for being "on call".

This is a very slippery slope - be very very careful because you are precariously close to giving up your own personal time, and this will have **drastic effects on your personal and professional life**.

Comment: Agreed. With the current situation, you absolutely do not want a company phone without much more discussion. By which I mean: Agreed on-call hours when you are expected to be available, and appropriate compensation for being available regardless of whether you are actually called, plus additional compensation if you are actually called. 

In the meantime, the appropriate response is simply "I'm not in the office right now so I can't assist - you'll need to speak to whoever is on site today."

Answer (score 12):

I want to expand on the comment from Wesley Long:  "Your mistake is in letting the receptionist decide what an "emergency" is.

You should talk to the receptionist and simply retract the option to contact you in an emergency.  Emergencies are not determined by the receptionist, but your manager.  Your receptionist is not being mean, but she is simply incapable of making those decisions, and obviously all IT issues are "emergencies" because **she** can't fix them.

The receptionist could use a hand on how to handle these calls, so advise her to say something like the following:

> Please follow existing procedures when requesting for IT support. 
>   Please contact the staff that is available on site.  If you have
>   issues that requires immediate assistance from Mr. Just Do It, please contact Mr. Manager.

If someone asks for you specifically, advise the receptionist they can mention your co-worker is equally competent.  If they are *not* equally competent, then advise HR to hire someone that is.

If anyone have objections, advise them that having the receptionist forwarding the call to your personal phone is not an answer in any situation.  If you need to be contacted outside work hours, your manager can do that, but not the receptionist.

Comment: Depending on the culture, the receptionist "knows better", may be in a power trip, does not care, or just wants to see the "problem" behind her back with a minimum of effort.

Answer (score 11):

First talk to the receptionist. Tell her that you don't want her to give your private phone number to anyone, that you don't want her to connect anyone to your private phone number, that your private phone number is private, and if she doesn't understand that, then you will have to talk to HR about it.

If you get calls, instead of not answering, you answer the phone, and tell them that they called your private phone number. When they ask you to do something, you tell them again that they called your private phone number. Until they get it.

Answer (score 6):

Your personal phone is yours and yours only. Your employer, can not expect you to answer work related calls on your personal phone, unless this has been written into your contract.

But, if you refuse to take calls flat out, it might be taken as a hostile action and will not make you friends where you work. The balance is delicate. If you have a company given phone, ask the receptionist or whomever to call you only on this number. If you have such phone, you can completely ignore the personal cell phone and nobody has anything to say.

In my personal case, only my immediate supervisor has access to my personal cell phone, just in case doo-doo hits the fan and my work cell is not going through. Never had to answer a work related call on my personal mobile phone, since I started working for my current employer.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't agree more with your second paragraph, my boss has my personal phone, but he sometimes calls me through the receptionist. So I also answer because I think it might be him

Answer (score 3):

> ... if I have the right to ask for a company phone specific for the purpose to receive calls transferred from the receptionist.

You can ask, but that doesn't mean you will receive. And it's likely not what you want. When you get a company phone two things will happen.

1. You will now "have" to answer that phone, encroaching even more on your personal time. You will have basically said, "I want a company phone, so you can call we 24/7 no matter what." That's not your goal.
2. When you don't answer your company phone, everyone will think it's more ok to try your personal phone. Your supposed to answer 24/7 now, maybe your battery is dead, try the "backup".

Now to address your real problem:

You want time away from work to be not work time. First thing is first. Use the biggest (figurative) mallet in your toolbox and beat the receptionist with it. Go to HR, her boss, your boss, the owner, anyone that will listen, and state the problem. "The receptionist is calling me on my personal line that she did not acquire officially." Don't play with this one. Make sure that you are clear the only course of action here, is for her to stop. No in between, no compromise, stop. If there is an emergency then **your** boss can call, or if your high enough on the org chart then a **equal manager or better** can call. You want this to be direct and pointed. Even flat out mean. You want to make sure you don't leave 1mm of wiggle room. Avoid statements like "If she call's me again..." cause you would have to follow through with them. But make it 100% clear that it's unacceptable. Lodge a complaint with HR if you need to. I can't stress enough, that to stop this you need to loose all the kind and nice wrapping and just "go fro the throat". Your actual goal should be getting her written up for abusing her position. It likely won't happen, but the fact that 10 people above her just had to go into CYA mode will have the desired effect.

Next time to pay for all that disruption. Your failure is that you don't have a system that lets people know these things (that they called you for). So create one. Use a ticketing system. Keep other managers informed. Make sure that the last thing you do for the weekend is update all the tickets, issues, whatever that will stay over the weekend with a status, even if that status is "still waiting for part". The idea is that managers should have the ability to check the status of the work they need done, without having to call you at home, either through team members, or better yet the ticketing system. You will need to spend some time "making up" for "being an ass over the phone thing" but implementing an easy to use system from tracking this kind of stuff will go a long way to helping avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

I find that the difficulty here is that it seems people are calling your work phone, and are being transferred to your cell without necessarily knowing it. (Tell me if I am wrong, because the rest of the answer depends on it).

They are not responsible for you getting those calls, and therefore are not expecting you to be anything different from when you are answering from the office.

Before your calls were being transferred, you would not be here to pick up the phone, so people would leave a message or send an email, or whatever.

Because of that, **it is OK to not answering your phone**. It will be just as before your calls were being transferred, and as if they were not transferred anymore. The only issue is with people who got used to call you and get an answer anytime.

Go back to the receptionist and make it clear that **you will not answer** professional calls on your personal cell, and transferring the call will simply be a waste of time for everybody.

Possibly advise your manager that you have been receiving professional calls on your cellphone, but that you won't be answering them anymore.

(Also, do what enderland says. Ask people to email requests whenever you pick up the phone. Maybe install an IT ticketing system. Talk to your manager about this, and about how getting calls all day long impedes your productivity.)

Comment: I'm not aware of any telephony switchboard technology that lets you transfer an incoming call manually to an external phone number.

Answer (score 2):

> Due to this, I wanted to ask if I have the right to ask for a company
>   phone specific for the purpose to receive calls transferred from the
>   receptionist.

Yes.

Tell the receptionist to stop transferring calls to your personal phone immediately.

Then tell your boss that if he wants you to receive calls when you are not at your desk that the company must provide a phone and a phone number. Otherwise, you'll get the call only when you return to your desk - his choice.

Companies should always provide the tools you need to do your job. If they don't provide a phone, then they have decided you don't need to be reachable.

Answer (score 0):

Establish boundaries; the phone is yours and yours alone; furthermore and even more important, it is your time.

I would not waste more energy with the receptionist, since you already talked with her and she dismissed you. Simply change the phone number, and she will get the message across; the situation is even more simple, as she is bellow you in the chain of the command.

However, since you mentioning your manager calling you through her, I would talk with him first, would explain the situation, and would tell him I would be changing to this number just to be used in emergencies by him, and only by him.

There are several points here:

- The fact is, that you carry a mobile, you cannot let people feel entitled to call you whenever pleases them;
- More importantly, define how do you prefer to be contacted depending on the severity of the problem; I do prefer email to common day-to-day problems, google chat to help work mates, smses for rather urgent tasks, and well voice when the house is on fire, literally.
- Depending on your position, you should also know when to STOP answering calls. In a major malfunction, I tell people I am at work, and turn my phone to silence.
- If your colleagues do not respect the boundaries, depending on the situation, make an exception, but do remind them. "I do prefer to be contacted this way or another"
- when and if contacted by customers, establish who put them through, and reinforce with them the appropriate formal channels, and tell them you are not at work. People are not machines, and they will understand.
- People calling you outside your work hours should be seen as an exception and privilege, and not as an obligation.
- There are also occasions where it is expected you will be without a phone for a reasonable amount of time (e.g. sex, the gym, the shower , church, the doctor or the beach). Use this to your advantage.
- It is a severe lack of respect and professionalism to simply dial your number and put someone through. Determine who does that and *admonish* them.

In the present and past I already had similar problems:

- I had to give my private mobile number when I was hired, and somehow someone "by mistake" put it in a wide company database (that someone was from the helpdesk, and I believe it was a passive-aggressive measure out of self-interest). I simply changed it.
- I was an IT director/sysadmin/system admin in a country with complicated cultural problems, and to further complicate it, my predecessor instead of doing his job, spend all the time at the phone talking with customers (because we had an helpdesk). To say the least, I inherited the company phone with more than 4k contacts. To further complicate it, it was not difficult to bribe/intimidate/ask the helpdesk/receptionist to pass me a call at any day of the week, or time of the day, despite telling them they were not allowed to do that. (heck, an irate customer ringing you 10 times at 11PM in a Saturday is not for the faint of heart).
  I just started screening calls when I had the number identified, and not answering calls at all from unknown numbers. I reinforced the proper channels when called at work, and outside work, I only accepted calls from workmates and a small circle of people. I also reinforced a rule, that if a secretary/helpdesk wanted to pass me someone else, they would have to speak first with me and *explain* why the call was being handed to me instead of the help desk.
- A bad customer that was owning us money keep calling me every single day at 8PM just to annoy me. Again, changing numbers worked quite well.
- I had a micro controlling manager that simply thought it was his god given right to call me any time he pleased "because I had a company phone". I stopped answering his calls.

To say it again. Establish your boundaries. You are selling your time and attention when working, but the company do no own neither you nor your soul. Grow some thick skin if you have to.

As others said, only an handful people here have my mobile number. My direct manager and a coworker in the same level as me who I trust; and I give them my personal phone on the condition they wont pass it to anyone else.

About company phones, I personally would not ask for one assigned for myself. While it allows you to screen calls, you never know who is calling and in some cultures it gives an entitlement to some to call you. What I would propose to management is a department cellular and a fixed sum paid on rotation for a few IT guys being on-call. Whoever has the phone has to take the calls; obviously someone in holidays wont take the calls.

It would not hurt you also growing some attitude; when people come searching for me or others at lunchtime and it is clearly not an urgency, I remember them *it is lunchtime*. I assume by your posts you should be young; do not be afraid of asserting yourself. People will respect more you for that.

Disclaimer: I am not advising ignoring people, being unreasonable of being inflexible. I am  advocating trying to enforce proper channels to be able to have a small semblance of separation between professional and personal time, especially when dealing with unreasonable situations.

Comment: “Simply change your phone number”. Do you have any idea what kind of trouble changing my phone number would be? I have no intention to change my phone number _ever_.

Comment: It depends on what number you give people. In a couple of decades of work, I have never have given my fixed number.

Answer (score -1):

> The one transferring all the calls is the receptionist, I once had to
>   call in due to a sickness and well she kept my phone. I've asked her
>   several times since the first incident that I don't want her to
>   transfer calls to my personal phone unless it's an emergency. Her
>   response was a bit neutral but agreeing to my request, and I thought
>   that was the end of it, yet she keeps transferring the calls
>   nonetheless.

(if possible Block her calls on your personal phone), inform your Boss, inform her Boss.

CC them in an email like this:

You stored my personal phone number - a piece of personal information which you obtained since I called you from this phone when I was ill - stored it without my consent and use it against my explicit communicated wish and your own agreement. It is not my understanding of your role to escalate arbitrary IT issues to a level that peoples lunch-breaks are interrupted or family visits are disturbed. Should such a decision actually be your role, then we should clarify the proper procedures with [name of my boss] and [name of your boss].